# ordinal 1 could not be located in dynamic link library windows 10

Tags: windows, dll, vb6

Im trying to install a VB6 application on windows 10.But it comes up with an error stating "The ordinal 1 could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Program Files(86)\Application\msxml6.dll"

Must i register the dll? it works fine in windows 7 but only on windows 10 it comes up with that error.

Comment: It is an operating system DLL, it does not belong in that directory.  Good thing it failed, do avoid destroying the machine.

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: It is already available and registered, present in c:\windows\syswow64.  Do nothing.  Discovering that you need a VM to keep old VB6 code and installers working is very common.